# Storage tab in spark UI shows a serialized memory value as "Size in Memory" for a cached RDD which is much less than the original data size on disk

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am just trying to understand the memory usage concept while caching (or persisting) a dataframe or rdd. I know `spark.memory.storageFraction` decides the size limit of data which can be persisted as memory only. And also I understand that  `.cache()` on a dataframe by default calls `persist()` with `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK` , while on rdd , `.cache()` calls `persist()` with `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY`. Now in below code snippet I am reading a single text file of 693 MB from HDFS using rdd textFile API and caching it. Then I am calculating count.

```
rdd1=spark.sparkContext.textFile("/public/cards/largedeck.txt").cache()
print(rdd1.count())
```

So as I understood it should use `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY`. But what I can see on spark UI is as below
[image]

[image]

It shows only `11.8 MB` of memory size on storage and `100% fraction cached`. From storage level I can see , its a serialized memory. Even if I am explicitly mentioning `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)` instead of `.cache()` , it still gives me a serialized memory.

I would like to understand how 693 MB data on disk became 11.8 MB serialized cached data by applying `.cache()`or `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)`?

Comment: The string representation of a double number is much larger than the 8 byte representation of a double in memory.

Comment: I am reading here entire row as a string using textFile API and underlying file is also a .txt file,  so how data type matters here?
Secondly why it comes as 'Memory serialized 1x Replicated' while I am not using a serialized StorageLevel (StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

Comment: Even i am seeing the same behavior. SQL tab says its using deserialized but storage tab shows  serialized!